# align text to bottom on two divs inside div

Tags: html, css

How do I format my CSS so that the text inside "header-right" should be aligned at the bottom while my image at "header-left" is aligned at the top?

Here's my html:

```html
<div class="container">     
    <div class="header-left;">      
         <img src="img1.png">   
    </div>  
    <div class="header-right;">         
         <div style="float:left;">
              This text should be at the bottom.
         </div>
         <div style="float:left;">
              This text should be at the bottom also.
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.:)

Comment: the text is already at the bottom of the image...what do you want your results to look like?

Comment: sorry what I mean is for the text to show at the bottom inside the div. here's a sample design: [link](http://www.macrowebcafe.com/images/text.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your class-naming I suppose you want both texts to the right of the image, bottom-aligned with the image?

To achieve this, apply `display: inline-block` to all DIVs , in addition apply `display: block;` to the image to avoid any space at its bottom:

```css
.header-left,
.header-right,
.header-right div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.header-left img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header-left">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/80x120">
  </div>
  <div class="header-right">
    <div>
      This text should be at the bottom.
    </div>
    <div>
      This text should be at the bottom also.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

BTW: Don't use a semicolon in `class="header-right"` (inside your DIV-tags) and similar.

Comment: Thanks for this! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can displat the .container as a table and the .header-right and .header-left as table cells. This way, you can align the contents vertical bottom (or even top or middle)

See snippet below

```css
.container{
display:table;
}
.header-left,.header-right{
display:table-cell;
}
.header-right{
vertical-align:bottom;
}
.header-right *{
display:table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">     
    <div class="header-left">      
         <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSYTogPdYlS2zHfImUPfjdkO1v0793TjQMD2qjLoY7qNkqCUN_-dA">   
    </div>  
    <div class="header-right">         
         <div style="">
              This text should be at the bottom.
         </div>
         <div style="">
              This text should be at the bottom also.
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this also! :)